# How to change the title Filament login page

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sI8E.png

I want to change "Laravel" on login page to the other words. What I should do on filament file. I can't see the code that show about "Laravel" and change the "Sign in" button to "Login" button.

Comment: Edit the .env file and change the line APP_NAME=Laravel

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your `.env` file located in your project root. Find the `APP_NAME` line and change the value to whatever you want the title to be. If your new app name is multiple words, remember to wrap it in quotes like so:

```
APP_NAME="My New App"
```